# aEntities.savechange() not working

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using a Windows forms application with Entity Framework 5, all my model is constructed by entity (`.edmx`). That means for model creating it made a connection string in my `app.config` file:

```
<add name="PGDEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ModelTest.csdl|res://*/Model.ModelTest.ssdl|res://*/Model.ModelTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=My-PC;initial catalog=DB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My problem is that when I run my code on another computer then

```
aEntities = new PGDEntities();
aEntities.ModelName.Add(aModel);
aEntities.SaveChanges();
```

it throws an exception

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

It might be for the entity connection string, but I change my connection string to

```
<add name="PGDEntities" 
     connectionstring="metadata=res://*/Model.ModelTest.csdl|res://*/Model.ModelTest.ssdl|res://*/Model.ModelTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=MyOther-PC;initial catalog=DB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" 
     providername="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But it wouldn't go forward.

Can any one explain the problem or the solution. Because when I want to deploy it in user side then it will occur again for sure. I can't figure it out, please anyone help me

Comment: Would you see the inner exception then, and tell us what is says also? oh, and yeah, your connection string is definitely fishy.

Comment: You have `data source=MyPC` in your connection string - this needs to be adapted to whatever other computer you're program is running on - you need to supply the name of the machine where the SQL Server instance is running on here.